# A Virtual Dedicated IP for HTTP Requests?

Tags: ip

**The issue:**

An online webadmin I use requires me to give them my IP before I can use their site. They add the IP to their "allowed" list and I can then login. I just moved to a new apartment where a dedicated IP for myself is no longer possible. In fact, the IP changes a few times weekly which is odd considering it rarely ever changed elsewhere. I cannot call them 3-5 times a week with a new IP :(

**The question:**

What's the easiest and/or cheapest way to get or fake a dedicated IP? I'm not very savvy when it somes to this stuff, so the only solution I could think of is to get a dedicated server, remote into that, and check the site from there. But that solution is mucho expensivio.

What other options are out there?

Comment: I need a solution that projects my outgoing IP as static (vs. a solution where an outsider visits a static IP which redirects incoming to me).

Comment: If you're using some shared internet access: are you sure the IP address you see is not some internal address? The address your webadmin sees is the same as you see at, for example,  http://whatismyipaddress.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to ask them to enable reverse DNS and give them that - but it would mean that if your IP is shared with everyone in the apartment, anyone may have access.

Other is to ask your ISP for a static IP, or *try* to get a router / device that can stay on 24/7 and renew the lease - when I was on a old ISP, I managed to have the same IP for 3 years... but then I went on holiday and as it was a long one, I turned everything off and lost it.

The last solution, you said is to get a dedicated server - You do not need to go that far. If you really want to go down this route, try to find a Linux or other VPS (Virtual Private Server) provider, some of them can be as low as £5 a month, from here, you should be able to set up a VPN or other tunnel and go via that. Also, having a VPS would give you other benefits that you may like.

Comment: Good luck... A lot of ISPs flatly refuse to give static IPs. I wish mine would give them.

Comment: @Fake Name switch ISP's then! If you are doing anything that requires a static IP, then you should switch if they won't give one. Many simply require a fee and will give.

Comment: I would if I could.
No one else is available where I live.

Answer (score 0):

Give your ISP a call, most sell static IPs for anywhere between $2 - $5 a month.

Comment: It's funny that a small VPS (with a static IP included) may cost the same as just a static IP (which can be used from one apartment only).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [some proxy server](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/)? And *maybe* services like [www.hidemyass.com](http://www.hidemyass.com) use some fixed IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should get a new provider.

They [should] know better than to restrict logins by public IP address. What if you need to log in from work? Or through a proxy? Or from your friend's house? Or from your phone?

If you can't switch providers, then I suggest that you consider calling them 3-5 times per week to let them know how their policy works in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Amazon Elastic IP addresses](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1346) then run an EC2 instance at the times you need to access the site. Elastic IP addresses cost 2.4 cents / day AFAICS, and you'd only pay for the instance during the time you are using it.